# List directoties down one level, excluding some named directories and files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to send a list of all folders including one level down to a txt file. Excluding some named folders and no files.
Imagine a folder structure like this. CAPS are folders.

```
FOLDER 1

.hidden

TEMP

somefile

=========

=========

FOLDER 2

.hidden

TEMP

DATA1

DATA2

somefile

========

========

FOLDER 3

.hidden

TEMP

DATA1

somefile
```

I would like to run "insert magic command here" and end up with an output that looks like below

```
FOLDER 1

FOLDER 2

DATA1

DATA2

FOLDER 3

DATA1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to create your folder structure:

```sh
for     f in    FOLDER\ 1 FOLDER\ 2 FOLDER\ 3
do      mkdir   -p "$f/TEMP"
        touch   "$f/.hidden" "$f/somefile"
        case    "$f" in
        (*2)    mkdir -p    "$f/DATA1/TEMP" "$f/DATA2/TEMP";;
        (*3)    mkdir -p    "$f/DATA1/TEMP"
        esac
done
```

That created a tree like:

```
find .
```

---

```
.
./FOLDER 1
./FOLDER 1/TEMP
./FOLDER 1/.hidden
./FOLDER 1/somefile
./FOLDER 2
./FOLDER 2/TEMP
./FOLDER 2/.hidden
./FOLDER 2/somefile
./FOLDER 2/DATA1
./FOLDER 2/DATA1/TEMP
./FOLDER 2/DATA2
./FOLDER 2/DATA2/TEMP
./FOLDER 3
./FOLDER 3/TEMP
./FOLDER 3/.hidden
./FOLDER 3/somefile
./FOLDER 3/DATA1
./FOLDER 3/DATA1/TEMP
```

And last I did...

```sh
find . ! -path './*/*/*' ! -name TEMP -type d
```

---

```
.
./FOLDER 1
./FOLDER 2
./FOLDER 2/DATA1
./FOLDER 2/DATA2
./FOLDER 3
./FOLDER 3/DATA1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that worked great I forgot that .hidden was a folder as well so added that into the find command. Find was outputting the folders in the order they were added so used the sort command to sort back into alphabetical order.  So I ended up with

```
find . ! -path './*/*/*' ! -name TEMP ! -name .hidden -type d | sort > folderlist.txt
```

Cleaned up the result a bit with

```
sed -n -e 's;^.*/;;p'
```

So it lists as

FOLDER 1

FOLDER 2

DATA1

DATA2

FOLDER 3

DATA1

Finally ended up with this beast of a line

```
find . ! -path './*/*/*' ! -name TEMP ! -name .hidden -type d | sort | sed -n -e 's;^.*/;;p' > folderlist.txt
```

Might be messy but hey I'm no expert. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you only want the file names without path, pass `-printf "%f\n"` to find. No need to use sed.

Comment: I did try that but couldn't get it to sort right, probably me being thick.